# Calculator for time complexity of recursive functions

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

Is there an online tool that returns the time complexity of recursion functions?

For instance, when I enter $T(n) = T(n/2) + n$, I'd like to get $\Theta(n)$.

[I tried using Wolfram Alpha,](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%3Dg%28n%2F2%29%2Bn) but it doesn't return the above result I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is giving you a more accurate estimate, $T(n) \sim 2n$. However, it can also give you the weaker estimate $T(n) = O(n)$ you are after:

[image: Wolfram Alpha screenshot]

Just click on *Show weaker bound*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use my [master theorem solver](https://www.nayuki.io/page/master-theorem-solver-javascript) to get tight asymptotic bounds. Using your example:

[image: Master theorem solver]